# Why does "put up with" mean "stand, endure"

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrasal-verbs

I'm a student learning English. Whenever I get stuck on phrasal verbs, I imagine the idiomatic meaning with the literal meaning and figure it out.

> **put up with**
>   Tolerate; endure.
>   *‘I'm too tired to put up with any nonsense’*
>   ([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/put_up_with))

However, based on its literal meaning, I'm finding it difficult to understand how ‘put up with’ means "endure", "tolerate" or "support" as its synonyms suggest.

It'll be really helpful for me, if someone could explain.

Comment: @Nigel j If so, how should i accept this expression if it's not explain in a practical sense? Memorizing is only the right way ?? Thank you for your answer

Comment: You have to memorise the meanings. Exactly the same problem exists in words with prepositions, whether in English or other languages: sometimes you can infer it but sometimes you can't.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

People "put up" poles to support something … [curtain poles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zhOfnzZ9og) for instance.

> …it can be a really easy job **putting up** a curtain pole…

So, you **put up** curtains **with** [the use/aid/assistance of] a pole. In other words,  *putting up* a pole means to support (tolerate) the weight of something.

Comment: Now i can make sense with this.  Like when i put A up with B, A will hold b in high position and A gotta bear the weight of B, it's gonna be a hard work. So they use "put up with" to mean "endure,stand". Am i right ??

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Please give supporting references. The answer below is obviously far more than personal speculation on the part of the answerer.

Comment: Of course English native speakers use the expression 'put up' to mean 'assemble / erect'. Do the B&Q workers / advertisers mention the relevant point, that 'put up with' = 'tolerate', certainly derives from this usage? Totally unscholarly reasoning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But a reference form OED that says, and I quote directly from Laurel's answer `"[p]erhaps originally a fig[urative] use of" this sense of "put up"` Is that definite proof? Isn't that too speculation? I gave an original and logical answer. In its simplicity, I *like* it

Comment: You know the advice here about subjective answers. You don't even indicate that this is largely speculation. OED have the grace to do so, despite undoubtedly vastly greater research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP did not express any interest  in its history, I was the one who added the etymology tag when I edited, and clarified the question. Maybe you should rollback the edit?

Comment: @Mari-LouA 'So please basing on the literal meaning, explain why that means it.' Which is what you do here. With no evidence at all that it is more than a guess. And with a speculation at odds with that suggested by OED, who admit that their suggestion cannot be regarded as indisputable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and when we put up a shelf is it not to "support" the weight of  objects such as books, glasses, plates, etc. ? Is it so far-fetched and so speculative?

Comment: I haven't got immediate access to OED, but I'd be far more confident that '[p]erhaps originally a fig[urative] use of" the sense 'To place in a receptacle for safe keeping or for future use; to store, stow away; to lay aside, put by; (in later use also) to pack or make up into a parcel, in a basket, etc.' is based on rather more than conjecture. Why choose _that_ sense? They subject these pronouncements to peer pressure.

Comment: What's interesting to me is that neither this answer nor any of the other answers explains the use of **with**. If I had never heard the expression before, I might think to say *I will put up your idea* (as in "put up a picture," "prop up a tottering structure,"  or "hold up something for all to see"), but the use of **with** implies that it's the thing itself that is being used to *aid* in the process. Yet, it seems that it *should* be "I will put up [whatever] **despite** it." In my mind, anyway, that's how I've always interpreted the expression. The "thing" is only grudgingly allowed . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford  (notifying a user 5 years later) I suggest that my *speculative* explanation of **with**  in **put up with** is quite likely. If I use a tool to put something up, *with* the aid of a tool. As for meaning and usage: I cannot *put up **with** his snoring, what other preposition would fit just as sunugly?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your criticism would have validity if the OP asked for its origin. They didn't. I added the etymology tag, which I realise was utterly wrong, the OP wanted an explanation that would help them understand and memorise the meaning. My answer was attempting precisely that.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I'd say that explaining different senses for words / expressions necessarily involves post-acceptance-into-the-lexicon etymology; the tag is required. Giving 'perhaps this might help you remember ... it might even be true' answers doesn't belong on ELU.

Comment: I don't think that putting up a pole means to tolerate the weight of something. I'm putting up with his bad behavior, however, does mean tolerate or endure....

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the etymology.

An earlier (now obsolete) version of this idiom is just "put up", which dates at least as far back to this 1573 quote:

> Al this I put up quietly.
>   <sub>[Letter-Book of Gabriel Harvey A.D. 1573-1580](https://archive.org/stream/letterbookgabe00camduoft#page/48/mode/2up/search/put+up+quietly)</sub>

The Oxford English Dictionary believes it is "[p]erhaps originally a fig[urative] use of" this sense of "put up":

> To place in a receptacle for safe keeping or for future use; to store, stow away; to lay aside, put by; (in later use also) to pack or make up into a parcel, in a basket, etc.

This sense is still used in some regions of the United States ("south. and south Midland"), although I think most people won't be familiar with it. An example can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ACApPO-A3OYC&pg=PA384&lpg=PA384&dq=%22I+went+upstairs+and+put+up+my+camera+and+came+back+and+went+with+him.%22&source=bl&ots=shG0LpRYrX&sig=xQqfM-fSdb69KwH5RGWQIlZ3fTw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU673oiv3aAhUlwVkKHeVgAc8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20went%20upstairs%20and%20put%20up%20my%20camera%20and%20came%20back%20and%20went%20with%20him.%22&f=false).

---

So, based on the etymology, you can think of the expression like you're bottling up your reaction and putting it away.

Comment: Is that the same sense of "put up" as "putting up preserves"? That's still in widespread use, isn't it? Or is it different? Anyway I'm not sure I see the connection. When you "put up with" something, that doesn't (necessarily) mean that you're bottling up your resentment for future use, does it?

Comment: @bof Yeah that seems to be definitely related, although it's listed under a different, more specific sense in the OED. I'm not sure how widespread it is (I've never heard of it but then again I don't make preserves). As for your second point, the emotion doesn't have to be resentment and you don't have to ever react to it—but both "bottling up feelings" and "putting up with something" have the connotation to me that something is wearing down your patience. Another, perhaps better idiom would be to say that you're "swallowing" the reaction.

Comment: "Putting up" peaches or beans (whatever was in abundance)--that is, home canning--was common when canned goods were more expensive and fresh produce was more seasonal.  Not "putting up with" nonsense is thus refusing to keep it around, not having it in the house.

Comment: So if I [put up with somebody's bad behavio(u)r](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-up-with-sth-sb) I bottle it and keep it aside, I preserve it? Nope, I have never ever considered that to be the meaning of "put up with" In fact, if one looks at its synonyms we have "support", "bear", "stand", "support", "endurance",  "tolerate", "tough it out" and to ["suffer through"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_up_with). I don't see "conserve",  "preserve", or "bottling"  anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to Etymonline the idiomatic expression [put up with](https://www.etymonline.com/word/put) is an extension of   the earlier  version “put up” in the sense of to accept, to pocket:

> To put up with "tolerate, accept" (1755) was originally to put up, as in "to pocket."

Answer (score 0):

In golden old days when vocabulary was being invented, there was a stage on to which people were put even if they liked each other or not. From there this terminology was invented hence bearing the meaning of "to tolerate".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The other answers are currently more convincing; do you have references?

Comment: In "golden old days", which era? Was it 15th century or later? For some, the 1960s was a golden era. And what do you mean by "stage", is it the raised platform  in a theatre? So people were forced onto a stage and perform in public? Or are you thinking of the gallows?